# Big-O of a Function

Tags: functions, asymptotics

Given $F(N) = 55N(600 + 50N \log N + 20N) + 20N(30N + 20\sqrt N)(50 + \log N)$.

How can one combine multiplication with addition for a Big-O estimate by algebraic means? I'm used to simply taking the bigger terms of simpler expressions as the Big-O (i.e. $10 + 3N^2 + 20 = O(N^2)$).

Comment: I have not gotten to this as of yet, but algebraically it would make sense that you would first simplify the equation above and then take the largest "degree" term which would out-run all of the others in the long-run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just expand it.
$$F(N) = a_1N + a_2N^2\log N + a_3N^2 + (a_4N^2 + a_5N\sqrt N)(a_6+\log N)$$
$$F(N) = a_1N + a_9N^2\log N + a_7N^2 + a_8N\sqrt N+a_5N\sqrt N\log N$$
$$F\in O(N^2\log N)$$

Note that I've replaced all the constants with arbitrary variables, since they don't matter anyways.